# CSS - Linking to custom fonts - Regular is working, Bold is not

Tags: css, fonts

I inherited Helvetica Neue fonts from a designer, and I need to use them in the site. [A screenshot of what fonts I got.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16876271/fonts.png) (I only care about regular and bold.)

1. My regular font is working, but my `strong` is not! Why? [Here is what it looks like in the site.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16876271/fonts2.png)
2. Can I combine these too definitions for bold and regular into one line?

PS. I am using Bootstrap if that makes a diff.

**CSS**

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
   src: url('../fonts/helvetica-neue/regular.woff');
 }
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Bold';
    src: url('../fonts/helvetica-neue/bold.woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    }

.and-then-something-like {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Try this : If you are going to define the `font-weight` as `bold` on the font-face declaration you must use the same `font-family` name as the regular. You declare the font as HelveticaNeue not NeueBold

Comment: ^ Why that did the job. I removed Bold from the declaration. Thanks! Do I need to have a separate decl. for each weight, or is there a more condensed syntax I can use?

Comment: You need a separate decl for each one since are separate files to load.  :) Glad to help U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have each `src` in a different `font-face`, look at this example taken from Google fonts.

In your example you are changing the `font-family` name (which is fine) but then whenever is `bold` you would have to give that changed name.

It is better to keep the same `font-family`.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Josefin Sans'), local('JosefinSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinsans/v9/xgzbb53t8j-Mo-vYa23n5ugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Josefin Sans Bold'), local('JosefinSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinsans/v9/C6HYlRF50SGJq1XyXj04z3NuWYKPzoeKl5tYj8yhly0.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```